# How to debug with cell magic %debug

Tags: debugging, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have troubles trying to use %debug cell magic to debug my code:
i am running ths cell

```
processData(newDataPath='Data/X_old.csv', newSourcePath='./Data - Feb-June-2019.xlsx', destPath='Data/X_2018_2019.csv')
```

which give me a key error: `data['quantity']`
quantity key error ....

how can i use %debug to see `data.columns` for exemple. Whatever i try to print in ipbb, i have the error is not defined: `newDataPath` is not defined, `data` is not defined etc

If you need more details please feel free to ask

Thanks

Comment: key error means `quantity` column is not present in the data DataFrame. Just fetch the data, and do print(data.columns)

Comment: I know... my question is about how to use %debug

Comment: You can import `from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace` and put `set_trace()` just before the line in the cell where you want to see columns

Comment: process data is an imported function, i thought there was a way to run it line by line and access local variables into it.... but maybe it is not possible

Comment: Use pycharm, debugging is easy in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out:
use `u` command to step back until my variable is defined, or u 1000 to come back at the start and `d` to execute step by step